# Post em Formulário com Campos Dinâmicos

Tags: php, formulário

Olá. Estou com problemas ao submeter os dados de um formulário.
Meu problema é o seguinte:

Meu cliente criou uma série de produtos no banco de dados. E agora ele precisa de um formulário em que aparecerão todas as quantidades dos produtos criados. Neste formulário ele irá atualizar a quantidade de produtos disponíveis.

Não há limite para a criação de produtos. Então pode ser que amanhã o formulário possua mais ou menos campos para serem preenchidos.

Eu consegui gerar o formulário da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$produtos     = array();
$sql          = "select * from tb_produto";
$search_query = mysql_query($sql);

while($select = mysql_fetch_array($search_query)){
    $id_produto = $select["id_produto"];
    $titulo = $select["titulo"];
    $quantidade = $select["quantidade"];
    array_push($produtos, $titulo);
    ?>

    <div>
        <label><?php echo $titulo; ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="txtQuantidade" value="<?php echo $quantidade; ?>">
    </div>
    <?php

}
?>
```

Agora eu preciso submeter estes dados. Minha dúvida é: como é possível submeter um formulário formado por uma quantidade de campos desconhecida de uma só vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar o id do produto no name dessa forma:

```
 <input type="text" name="txtQuantidade<?php echo $id_produto; ?>" value="<?php echo $quantidade; ?>">
```

e dar post do form, recuperando o id e valor dele para dar update desta forma:

```
while (list ($chave, $valor) = each ($_POST))   {
    reset ($_POST);
    if (substr($chave,0,13) == "txtQuantidade") {
        $guardaid = substr($chave,13);
        $sql_alteracao = "update tb_produto set quantidade = ".$_POST['txtQuantidade'.$guardaid]." where id_produto = ".$guardaid;

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Me ajudou muito!!!

Infelizmente não tive tempo de testar a solução até hoje. Mas acabo de implementar algo baseado no que você sugeriu e funcionou perfeitamente.

Obrigado!!!